# Swift - UICollectionView didSelectItemAt is not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  var model = CardModel()

  //Kepp track of the cards veiwed
  var cardArray = [Card]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Call the getCards method of the card model

    cardArray = model.getCards()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
  }

   // MARK: -UICOlecctionView Protocol Methods

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return cardArray.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Get a card CardCollectionViewCell object
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell

    //Get the card that the collection view is trying to display
    let card = cardArray [indexPath.row]

    //Set the card for the cell
    cell.setCard(card)

    return cell
  }

  func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   print("Cell is taped: \(indexPath.row)")

   let cell =  collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell

    // Flip the card
    cell.flip()
  }
}
```

I have an issue when I tap on the card to flip. The did select function is not getting called as I tested it for a print function and it shows that it's not tapping at all. Can some help please?

Comment: check storyboard if the collectionview has user interaction enabled, same for the cell

Comment: Does the viewcontroller inherit both `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource`?

Comment: check if the contentview of the cell(elements added to the cell)  prevents the tap gesture to pass through, resulting in the collectionview cell not having the tap gesture being recognised